# TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header' - when i use header,403 error - without header

Tags: python, html, python-requests, http-status-code-403

i am trying **scrape** information from [this](https://www.accuweather.com/en/bd/dhaka/28143/current-weather/28143) website but keep getting status code: **403**,
So tried using header but got **TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'**

***Code:***

```
import requests

head = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0'}
url = "https://www.accuweather.com/en/bd/dhaka/28143/current-weather/28143"
pageObj = requests.get(url, header = head)
print("Status code: " + str(pageObj.status_code)) # *for testing purpose*
```

***Error:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python/PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3/Workshop/WEB_SCRAPING/test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    pageObj = requests.get(url, header = head)
  File "F:\Python\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3\Workshop\WEB_SCRAPING\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Python\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3\Workshop\WEB_SCRAPING\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'
```

[header from firefox dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbAcZ.png)

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of the argument is `headers`, not `header`. See the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects).

Use `pageObj = requests.get(url, headers=head)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `header` in `params`:

```
import requests
head = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0'}
url = "https://www.accuweather.com/en/bd/dhaka/28143/current-weather/28143"
PARAMS = {'header':head} 
pageObj = requests.get(url, params = PARAMS)
```

Comment: what is "params" used for?i get that headers is used for some kind of proxy